# Android Notification Bar Color Changed to White along with the Text

Tags: java, android

This is a simple layout for tabs. The Android notification panel turns white when I switch to this page. I tried changing the colors and checked the Android notification panel, but it's still white and the text is white too. Its white background + white text, so users can see any notifications.

What might be causing this?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYj2G.jpg)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Tabb">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/primaryDark"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        android:elevation="3dp">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:minHeight="?actionBarSize"
            android:text="Bookings"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:elevation="5dp"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/grey"
            android:elevation="5dp"/>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:itemBackground="@color/grey"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/selector"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_navigation"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: post your colors.xml here..maybe you changed your colorprimarydark value

Comment: Code: ```<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <resources> <color name="primary">#3898EC</color> <color name="primaryDark">#3898EC</color> <color name="primaryTransparent">#1F2196f3</color> <color name="accent">#03A9F4</color> <color name="drawerBackground">#ffffff</color> <color name="drawerText">#424242</color>```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this in your color.xml:

```
     <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#000000</color> //add your hex code color for notification bar
```

or use in java

```
        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorprimarydark));
```

Comment: Thank you for this but it still shows white Notification Bar with white/invisible text.

Comment: @PrashantT have you seen my edit? Does my second method worked?

Comment: Yesss. Thank you so much Wini. I have been at it for 2 days now and your method worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Check your styling..

There might be an issue with:

```
android:background="@color/primaryDark"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
```

Comment: There are 3 styles file:   <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
        <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
        <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>

Comment: V21 Style:  <style name="AppTheme" parent="BaseAppTheme">
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/black</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>

        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">false</item>
    </style>

Comment: V23 Style: <resources>
    <style name="AppTheme.Light" parent="AppTheme.BaseLight">
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/statusBarLight</item>
        <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>

Comment: The Colors XML Seems to be Good:  <color name="primary">#3898EC</color>
    <color name="primaryDark">#3898EC</color>
    <color name="primaryTransparent">#1F2196f3</color>
    <color name="accent">#03A9F4</color>

    <color name="drawerBackground">#ffffff</color>
    <color name="drawerText">#424242</color>

    <color name="statusBarLight">#eeeeee</color>
    <color name="navigationBarDark">#606060</color>

    <color name="black">#000000</color>
    <color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>

    <color name="grey">#252726</color>
    <color name="lightgrey">#AAAAAA</color>